# How do I get a Double out of a resultset instead of double?

Tags: java, jdbc

When working with a JDBC resultset I want to get Double instead of double since this column is nullable.  Rs.getDouble returns 0.0 when the column is null.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can check for [`wasNull`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull%28%29) on your ResultSet to find out if the value was `null`.

> Note that you must first call one of the getter methods on a column to try to read its value and then call the method wasNull to see if the value read was SQL NULL.

If you really need a `Double` afterwards, you can create it from the `double` returned.

Answer (score 15):

An alternative to the aforementioned `ResultSet#wasNull()` is to test [`ResultSet#getObject()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject%28java.lang.String%29) on `null` so that you can nicely put it in a single line in combination with the ternary operator:

```
Double d = resultSet.getObject("column") != null ? resultSet.getDouble("column") : null;
```

instead of

```
Double d = resultSet.getDouble("column");
if (resultSet.wasNull()) {
    d = null;
}
```

Comment: Interesting point, although there is a performance penalty here for calling a getter twice in the common case when the value is not null. Maybe it is possible just to cast the result of getObject to a Double?

Comment: @Yoni: There's certainly no performance penalty in invoking a simple getter. The data is *already* there since `next()` has been called.

Comment: but also note what the documentation of ResultSet says: `For maximum portability, result set columns within each row should be read in left-to-right order, and each column should be read only once.` :-@

Comment: @Carlos: that was specified over 15 years ago. This is really not an issue nowadays.

Answer (score 7):

Use ResultSet.wasNull -> http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull%28%29

Basically it works for all primitive types, you first use `getDouble`, `getInt`, etc., and then only if the result is 0 you use `wasNull`.

Answer (score 3):

You could just do:

Double d = (Double) resultSet.getObject("column");

then you don't have to worry if it was null.

Comment: Be careful, you may end with having an error like "ClassCastException 'java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Double'"

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin:

```
private fun ResultSet.getDoubleOrNull(columnIndex: Int): Double? when {

     this.getObject(columnIndex) == null -> null

     else -> this.getDouble(columnIndex)

}
```