# How to get Double.NaN for NULL (numeric) value from PostgreSQL in Java

Tags: java, postgresql, apache-commons-dbutils

I need to know if value (`numeric`) in Java ResultSet from PostgreSQL is `NULL` and if so, I would need to get `Double.NaN` instead of 0. I use Apache Commons DBUtils mapping but it maps NULL value to 0.

Is there some way how to get Double.NaN instead without need to create own `BasicRowProcessor`?

Comment: I strongly suspect you'll have to override or replace the underlying code. It would be completely incorrect for PgJDBC to return `Double.NaN` for `null`, since `NaN` is a legal non-null value for a float column. Why don't you just store `NaN` in the database anyway? Is it because (for some insane, wtf-were-you-thinking reason) Java's BigDecimal can't cope with `NaN`?

Comment: You are right, it doesn't have to be `Double.NaN` but I need to know, if original value in database table is `NULL` or `0`. Mapping I use from DBUtils makes `0` from `NULL` (missing value) what makes issues in my code.

Comment: check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158187/how-do-i-get-a-double-out-of-a-resultset-instead-of-double